# What is "one-nine-O"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

There is a scene in the movie *Michael Clayton* where after Michael and a cop discuss a murder the cop makes small talk by mentioning Michael's brother, who is in some sort of trouble.

> Cop: I know your brother a little. My wife works the **one-nine-O** out in Queens.
>
> Michael Clayton: I'll tell him hello.
>
> Cop: If something comes in, I'll get back to you.

I can't find anything online about this term. It is uttered in three separate words in the movie: one nine o. What does it mean?

Comment: Going out on a limb here: I don't know enough about M.C.'s background but I looked up the meaning of *190* as a police radio code, and it looks like it stands for (attempted) suicide (moreover, a cursory glance at the Wikipedia entry reveals what the movie deals with is in the same vein). So his wife works with suicidal people; a suicide hotline maybe?

Comment: @userr2684291 That sounds like a very reasonable guess. I think it just might be the answer.

Comment: It's not a suicide line. Cops work out of precincts in NYC., so it's the number of a precinct (fictional) in New York City. The 190 would be the 190th precinct. Don't you remember the question you asked yesterday where Michael's brother was saying he owes his balls to that cop and his wife? That wouldn't happen if she was working a suicide hotline, trust me.

Comment: @Robusto I just realized a misunderstanding I had about the film. I thought the cop that owes other people on Michael's behalf was a friend of Michael's. Just looked up on the movie's Wiki page. Turns out he is Michael's other brother Gene. Michael also has another brother Timmy who for most of the film is in hiding from debt collectors. I thought the 190 reference was about Timmy. Now that you clarifies it for me, it does seem it is Gene the cop that is talked about here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From Robusto's comment:

It's not a suicide line. Cops work out of precincts in NYC., so it's the number of a precinct (fictional) in New York City. The 190 would be the 190th precinct. Don't you remember the question you asked yesterday where Michael's brother was saying he owes his balls to that cop and his wife? That wouldn't happen if she was working a suicide hotline, trust me.